# Python Selemiun find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR

Tags: python, selenium, css-selectors

[image]

I'm trying to hit the button but it doesn't work

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type='submit']").click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ty by xpath:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@type='submit']").click()
```

Or

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[type='submit']").click()
```